# What is the hot key for 'content assist' in java editor for eclipse in mac?

Tags: macos

What is the hot key for 'content assist' in java editor for eclipse in mac?

It said '^ '

But can you please tell me what is '^ '?

Thank you.

Answer (score 11):

For me it's often broken in the predefined settings, I usually change it in Preferences -> Keys to be Command-Space (and change Spotlight to be Alt-Space in the Mac OS preferences).

Answer (score 6):

`^` is Control.

Answer (score 1):

By default it is control-spacebar, it is a bit hard to read on the Key Assist panel.

Answer (score 0):

`^` is `Shift`.
Press `Shift+Space` for content assist.
Note that if there's only one option to choose from in the content assist menu, you have to press `Enter\Return`, as `^Space` will act as just `Space`.